# Access denied for user root'@'localhost'

Tags: защита

Доброе время. Вот хотел поинтересоваться. Выскакивает у меня на проекте такая вот ошибка, допустим:

> `Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user        root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Ну вот по моей невнимательности, я неправильно поставил пароль. А вот нехороший дяденька, может воспользоватся данной ситуацией и порадовать меня чистой базой данных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Напрямую тут эксплуатировать, разумеется, нечего.**
- Но, тем не менее, косвенно это может помочь потенциальному злоумышленнику.

> - Имея информацию про то, что используется `MySQL` и подтверждение того, что в текущей конфигурации `error` и `warning-мессаджи` летят напрямую к пользователю, проводить атаку [**`SQL injection`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) становится проще.
> - Понятно, что возможности для ее проведения может и не быть, однако, если где-то все-таки есть уязвимый код, то вероятность его успешной эксплуатации увеличивается.

- Небольшое лирическое отступление по поводу функции `mysql_connect` вообще - [**она deprecated,**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php) соответственно, не стоит использовать ее вообще.
- Вообще, [**есть информация,**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888065/php-mysql-connect-security) что данные, передаваемые при аутентификации через `mysql_connect` могут быть перехвачены, если не используется `MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL` с зашифрованной передачей данных.

> Не знаю, насколько вероятен такой перехват в реальной жизни, но, как минимум, стоит задуматься.

Comment: А какой смысл уже проводить атаки вида sql injection, если сервер уже взломан, доступ рута украден. Все, гуд бай, Америка:

     Имея информацию про то, что используется MySQL и подтверждение того, что в текущей конфигурации error и warning-мессаджи летят напрямую к пользователю, проводить атаку SQL injection становится проще.

Тем более, в PHP даже есть специальная функция, которая в "умных" 
руках может снизить вероятность атаки типа инжекта sql кода - **mysql_real_escape_string().** 

---
Что по поводу "она deprecated", та ладно, кэп? =) Она стала таковой с появлением PDO, как минимум.

Comment: И Еще:

    Вообще, есть информация, что данные, передаваемые при аутентификации через mysql_connect могут быть перехвачены, если не используется MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL с зашифрованной передачей данных.

Та ладно? Почти все может быть неким образом перехвачено, если не используется такое безопасное шифрованное соединение SSL.

Comment: @Asen

- Обычно имеет смысл дочитывать вопрос хотя бы до конца, автор же написал *"Ну вот по моей не внимательности, я не правильно поставил пароль"* и поинтересовался, к чему это может привести.

- Я думаю, что по поводу безопасности `PHP + MySQL` можно много чего сказать, помимо `mysql_real_escape_string,` только к вопросу это будет иметь довольно посредственное отношение.

- Видимо, автор вопроса не знает, что `mysql_connect, mysql_pconnect, ...` являются `deprecated` и то, что для вас очевидно, может быть вполне себе неочевидным для других.

Comment: @Asen А какую цель вы преследуете этими комментариями? :) Если в моем ответе есть какие-то фактические ошибки, то готов их обсудить.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать

Даже представить себе не могу, как можно **"неправильно поставить пароль ПО НЕВНИМАТЕЛЬНОСТИ"**. По-моему, это какой-то бред...

---
Ошибок нет и быть не может, так как это ваши рассуждения в основном. Есть лишь небольшие замечания, про которые все расписано выше.

---
И, кстати:

     Я думаю, что по поводу безопасности PHP + MySQL можно много чего сказать...

Тоже не совсем согласен. Согласен с тем, что данная "связка" предоставляет множество хлопот и возни с безопасностью, но сама по себе она не является бажной и дырявой. Есть некоторые уязвимости, но они не фатальны.

Comment: @Asen Сама по себе не является дырявой? Один `PHP` [**чего стоит.**][1]

[1]: http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-search.php?f=1&vendor=&product=php&cveid=&cweid=&cvssscoremin=7&cvssscoremax=&psy=&psm=&pey=&pem=&usy=&usm=&uey=&uem=

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, да уж, с большинством их данных уязвимостей я знаком, но тут дело в том, что они, в основном, на уровне самого интерпретатора. Тем более, что многие уязвимости из данного списка уже давно пофиксены.

Comment: Хм.. Спасибо большое, много чего нового узнал))

Answer (score 2):

Привет!
Любые такие сообщения уже плюс для злоумышленника. Ставьте @перед функцией mysql_connect, чтоб не выводила сообщений или настройте вывод информационных сообщений (варнингов,ошибок и тд.) в php.ini. Рекомендуется на стадии разработки включить вывод всех ошибок, а при эксплуатации лучше таких вещей не показывать.

Comment: Он оно чё))) А перед mysql_fetch_array() ,или что в этом роде, тоже нужно ставить @?

Comment: @ перед функцией подавляет вывод ошибки

Comment: А лучше не пользоваться deprecated-функциями типа `mysql_connect`, если уж пользоваться PHP. Даже на [php.net/mysql_connect](http://php.net/mysql_connect) жирное красное предупреждение висит.